# firebase sdk set up not finishing

Tags: android, firebase

when I set up my firebase sdk, I have copied the json file, I have added all the required codes into project level build gradle and app level build gradle and synced it. but at my firebase it is still stuck at step 4 "Run your app to verify installation" (checking if the app has communicated with our servers)

The android project is built successfully.
[firebase issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQdmo.png)

[app level build gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbPgu.png)

[project level build gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj4e8.png)

Comment: What is the warning the you get?

Comment: well there is no warning . Its just stuck on step 4 for the longest time.